# Metadata ISO19139-3 validation Error Geonetwork 3.4.3

Tags: metadata, standards, iso, geonetwork

I'm trying to create a template for the last ISO19139-3 standard using Geonetwork 3.4.3. When I try to validate my metadata I got the error described in the attached image [image: ResourceConstraints _error]

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm not understanding what is missing.

Comment: What's the error exactly? because I can only see a XPATH in your image.

Comment: The error deals with the "**INSPIRE metadata implementing rule validation**" and it says this:  
_Constraints related to access and use. Conditions applying to access and use is missing_.
Please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: is there any error logged serverside when you run the validation?

Comment: @juanluisrp yes there is the catilina file. should I show it to you?

Comment: At least the fragment with the error stacktrace, yes.

Comment: here you can find the final rows of the log related to the validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190424/discussion-between-sylar-80-and-juanluisrp).

Comment: @juanluisrp I sent you a message in the chat because the log was too long to be posted here